# converting user input in python

Tags: python, string, format, coordinates

How can I convert the user input `go 30,45` to `go(30,45)`?

so far I have:

```
input = "go 30,45"
output = re.sub(r'go (\d+)', r'go(\1,\1)', input)
```

However this doesn't seem to be working, I know it is probably down to the (\1,\1) but what could I change to get the desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
inpt = "go 30,45"
output = re.sub(r'go (\d+,\d+)', r'go(\1)', inpt)  # 'go(30,45)'
```

Note that you should refrain from using `input` as a variable name since it is already reserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `re` as demonstrated by @A.R.S, but in this case, I would probably just use str builtin methods...

```
'{0}({1})'.format(*"go 30,45".split())
```